# Regex to find certain words in function body

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a regular expression to find the word after `$body->`
That is `userId`, `deviceId`, `deviceToken` and `deviceType` in the following code sample:

```
 function deviceUpdate($body)
 {  
    $userId=trim($body -> userId);
    $deviceId= $body -> deviceId;
    $deviceToken=trim($body -> deviceToken);
    $deviceType=trim($body -> deviceType);
 }
```

There can be a single space or multiple spaces after body keyword and after `->`

The regular expression I tried is:

```
(?<=body ->\s)\S+
```

But this does not work properly if there is no space between `body` and `->`.

Edit : I used the the regular expression **~function\s*(.+?)(~** to find the name of function ( deviceupdate) and **~\$body\s*->\s*(\w+)~** to find all keywords after body -> operator. It works perfectly fine. Suppose, i have 2 functions :

```
function deviceUpdate($body)
 {  
    $userId=trim($body -> userId);
    $deviceId= $body -> deviceId;

 }

function postad($body)
 {

    $adtitle = $body -> adtitle;
    $addescription = $body -> addescription;

  }
```

How to extract the function 1 name that is **deviceUpdate** and corresponding keywords in that same function after ***body ->*** that is ( userId,deviceId) in one array and function 2 name **postad** and corresponding keywords in that same function after ***body ->*** that is ( adtitle,addescription) in second array?

Currently when i use ***preg_match_all*** and regular expression as stated above  it returns everything it matches in a single array.

Comment: See here, it [works well](https://regex101.com/r/uT6tW0/1). What tool/language are you using?

Comment: Php. Yes but in the regex i have written, if there is no space between body and -> , it does not work

Comment: Then use [`\$body\s*->\s*(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/uT6tW0/2) and grab the value you need from Group 1.

Comment: @wiktor I tried using it sir. Thanks a lot. I want to capture only keywords ( userId, device Id etc. ) I dont want to capture ' ) ' or ' ; '  in group 1.

Comment: See my answer explaining how to do that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sir can you please suggest me a solution to my question .I have edited my question.

Comment: That will not look nice. I will try. Do you want them all in a single match, in different groups? I think it is not possible, you will need to use multple matches.

Comment: Try [`(?:\bfunction\s+(\w+)\([^()]*\)\s*\{|(?!^\G))(?:(?!}\h*\r?\n).)*?\$body\s*->\s*(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kE1tB5/1). See [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/5JO02v). Actually, this is difficult to do with a regex reliably. You might have issues if you do not have `}` followed with a newline to separate functions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Sir no issue in using multiple matches. There actually can be n such functions. I want a solution to find function name and corresponding keys as i stated above in different array.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Sir, i tried using it. http://ideone.com/48KXN1 . It is not working the way i want.

Comment: You can use [this one](https://regex101.com/r/kE1tB5/2). See [this demo](http://ideone.com/lm57qR).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  you are genius. !!! It works. Can u please explain the regex you have used

Comment: The question you asked is a different one. I cannot write that in the answer. The regex above uses a custom boundary specified with \G and a tempered greedy token making sure a match is only found inside one function.

Comment: That regex is not efficient and may cause issues with longer inputs. Not tested with long strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tested that with longer strings. Its working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your solution, you are using a *positive lookbehind* that, in PHP PCRE regex, cannot be of undefined length.

If you have cases where `$body` and `->` are separated with zero or more spaces, you cannot rely on a  fixed-width lookbehind. Use *capturing* and grab the submatch from the match object (to only match alphanumerics with underscore to avoid matching `);`, you need to replace `\S` with `\w`):

```
~\$body\s*->\s*(\w+)~
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT6tW0/3)

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/IxA5Lz):

```
$re = '~\$body\s*->\s*(\w+)~'; 
$str = " function deviceUpdate(\$body)\n {  \n    \$userId=trim(\$body -> userId);\n    \$deviceId= \$body -> deviceId;\n    \$deviceToken=trim(\$body -> deviceToken);\n    \$deviceType=trim(\$body -> deviceType);\n }"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // => userId
```

If you need *all matches*, use `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/yvGNDq)

**To address the edit**:

You can use

```
(?:\bfunction\s+(\w+)\([^()]*\)\s*\{|(?!^\G))(?:(?!\bfunction\s+\w+\([^()]*\)\s+{|}\h*\r?\n).)*?\$body\s*->\s*(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kE1tB5/2)

In PHP, use it as

```
$re = '~(?:\bfunction\s+(\w+)\([^()]*\)\s*\{|(?!^\G))(?:(?!\bfunction\s+\w+\([^()]*\)\s+{|}\h*\r?\n).)*?\$body\s*->\s*(\w+)~s';
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/lm57qR)

The regex above uses a custom boundary specified with `(?:\bfunction\s+(\w+)\([^()]*\)\s*\{|(?!^\G))` and a tempered greedy token `(?:(?!\bfunction\s+\w+\([^()]*\)\s+{|}\h*\r?\n).)*` making sure a match is only found inside one function

Comment: There can be other ways to write the regex (say, you want to match any text up to the `);`, then use [`\$body\s*->\s*(.+?)\);`](https://regex101.com/r/uT6tW0/4)), the point is to use capturing mechanism. You only showed one example. If you need a more precise help with the regex, please provide test cases.

Comment: @bobblebubble: That was just to show the concept of capturing. Then, there appeared the comment about what OP needs. Not a problem, I can remove that.

Comment: Yes, I see It was to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go `\(\h*\$body\h*->\h*\K\w+(?=\h*\))|=\h*\$body\h*->\h*\K\w+(?=\h*;)`

Comment: Now it matches the sneaky deviceId